# Team build of Web Projects generates App_web_xxxx.dll files and TFSBuild.Proj Script

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, web-applications, tfsbuild

I have a web application that has some non-web projects as well.

When using Web Deployment, a single assembly is generated for all the aspx.vb files.

When using Team Build (TS 2008), a lot number App_Web_xxx.dll file(s) are generated instead of a single assembly.

How can i solve this problem and change the TFSBuild.proj file so that it can generate a single Web Assembly instead of a lot number of assemblies.

Please help.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I guess thats because the MERGE operation is not occurring like it used to happen for Web Deployment Project in my solution. How can i enable MERGE of App_web_*.dll files into a single Web.dll assembly file and delete the satellite assemblies?

Here is my code from **TFSBuild.proj file:**
(MY web project is in Release|.NET Config and all other projects within the solution are in Release|Any CPU)

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|.NET' ">
      <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
      <OutputPath>.\Debug</OutputPath>
      <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
      <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
      <SingleAssemblyName>Web</SingleAssemblyName>
      <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>true</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|.NET' ">
      <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
      <OutputPath>.\Release</OutputPath>
      <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
      <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
      <SingleAssemblyName>Web</SingleAssemblyName>
      <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>true</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

Please tell me what are the corrections i need to do.,

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure your are passing in the parameters below into your build?

```
/property:Configuration="Release;Platform=.NET"
```

if not the build might not be using your property groups